# phpundercontrol doesn't find any tests

Tags: testing, phpdoc

PhpUndercontrol doesn't finde any test, inside my projects (inside cruisecontrol/projects) I have this:

/www/tests/DomainTEst/DomainTest.php  (for instance I want to run for now only one test)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myproject" default="build" basedir=".">

  <target name="build" depends="checkout,php-documentor,php-codesniffer,phpmd,phpunit" />
  <target name="checkout">
    <exec executable="git" dir="${basedir}/source" failonerror="on">
      <arg line="pull origin master"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="php-documentor"> 
      <exec executable="phpdoc" dir="${basedir}/source">
        <arg line="-ct type -ue on -t ${basedir}/build/api -tb /usr/share/php/data/phpUnderControl/data/phpdoc -o HTML:Phpuc:phpuc -d src/"/>
      </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="php-codesniffer">
    <exec executable="phpcs" dir="${basedir}/source" output="${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml">
      <arg line="--report=checkstyle --standard=PEAR --ignore=src/autoload src/"/>
    </exec>
  </target>  

  <target name="phpmd">
    <exec executable="phpmd" dir="${basedir}/source">
      <arg line="./src xml codesize,unusedcode,naming"/>
    </exec>
  </target>   


  //here is the problem I suppose!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  <target name="phpunit">                
    <exec executable="phpunit" dir="${basedir}/source" failonerror="on">
      <arg line="--log-junit ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml --coverage-xml ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.coverage.xml --coverage-html ${basedir}/build/coverage DomainTest www/tests/DomainTest/DomainTest.php" />
    </exec>
  </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you're getting back?

I think you need a leading slash before

```
www/tests/DomainTest/DomainTest.php
```

However, your unit tests, in PhpUnderControl, should be testing the code that is actually in your PhpUnderControl Directory, I believe, which should look something like this:

```
/opt/cruisecontrol/projects/your project name/your project tests folder
```

If your test folder is named "tests", and your "dir" in your PHPunit target is "${basedir}/source", you should only need to provide the relative path, which would be "test".